# (Selenium) Download and Rename File Problem

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using `selenium` to login a page, and download some tiff files, 
now i have a variable `downloadurl`, it contains an array of url links which i scraped from the website. now i am using the below code to download files:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome();
 driver.get(downloadurl)
```

I do get all files downloaded but with no names, eg. img(1), img(2) ...

Now my problem is: I want `driver.get(downloadurl)` download files one by one according to `downloadurl` array sequence, and rename the file right after  it is downloaded according to `title` variable which is an array, then download the next file, and rename...

**P.S.** I avoid to use requests because the login procedure is very complicated and requires authorization cookies.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: If you know it will be saved as `img(1)` initially, just have your script download the file, and then `os.rename()` the file from "img(1)" to whatever. Then rinse and repeat because they will all download with the same name.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

```
import os
import time

for downloadlink, uniqueName in my_list_of_links_and_names:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome();
    driver.get(downloadurl)
    time.sleep(5) # give it time to download (not sure if this is necessary)
    # the file is now downloaded
    os.rename("img(1).png", uniqueName) # the name is now changed
```

This will work assuming that "img(1).png" will be renamed and then the next download will come in as "img(1).png" yet again.

The hardest part would be making `my_list_of_links_and_names` but if you have the data in separate lists, just `zip()` them together. You can also generate your own title every loop based on some criteria...

Answer (score 0):

First we will create a function (Rename_file) that renames the downloaded image from its folder.

```
def Rename_file(new_name, Dl_path):  #Renames Downloaded Files in the path
    filename = max([f for f in os.listdir(Dl_path)])
    if 'image.png' in filename: #Finds 'image.png' name in said path
            time.sleep(2) #you can change the value in here depending on your requirements
            os.rename(os.path.join(Dl_path, filename), os.path.join(Dl_path, new_name+'.png')) #can be changed to .jpg etc
```

Then we Apply this function in array of url links:

```
for link in downloadurl: #Will get each link in download url array
    for new_name in title:
            driver.get(link) #download the said image in link
            Rename_file(new_name,Dl_path)
```

Sample code:

```
downloadurl = ['www.sample2.com','www.sample2.com'] 
Dl_path  = "//location//of//image_downloaded"
title  = ['Title 1', 'Title 2']

def Rename_file(new_name, Dl_path):  
    filename = max([f for f in os.listdir(Dl_path)])
    if 'image.png' in filename: 
            time.sleep(2)
            os.rename(os.path.join(Dl_path, filename), os.path.join(Dl_path, new_name+'.png'))

for new_name in title:
   for link in downloadurl: 
            driver.get(link) 
            time.sleep(2)
            Rename_file(new_name,Dl_path)
```

I'm quite sure on the Rename function I created but I haven't really tested this with an array of url links since I really can't think of where could I test it. Hopefully this works on you. Please let me know :-)